# Users list empty

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I'm trying to retrieve from RealTime-Database the list of users with their First name and second name but nothing appears.

The class UsersActivity show all the users from the database.I tried a lot of tutorials but nothing seems to work.

```
public class UsersActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView userslist;
    private DatabaseReference ref;
    private List<Users> mUsers;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView ( R.layout.activity_users );
        ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance ().getReference ().child ( "FirstName" );

        userslist = (RecyclerView) findViewById ( R.id.users_list );

        userslist.setHasFixedSize ( true );
        userslist.setLayoutManager ( new LinearLayoutManager ( this ) );


    }
    public void readUsers(){
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser= FirebaseAuth.getInstance ().getCurrentUser ();
        DatabaseReference reference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance ().getReference ("spors-budy-en866");
        reference.addValueEventListener ( new ValueEventListener () {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange (@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled (@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        } )
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart () {
        super.onStart ();
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Users> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Users> ()
                .setQuery ( ref, Users.class )
                .build ();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, FindFriendViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, FindFriendViewHolder> ( options ) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder (@NonNull FindFriendViewHolder findFriendViewHolder, int i, @NonNull Users users) {
                findFriendViewHolder.userName.setText ( users.getName () );

            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public FindFriendViewHolder onCreateViewHolder (@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from ( parent.getContext () ).inflate ( R.layout.users_template, parent, false );
                FindFriendViewHolder viewHolder = new FindFriendViewHolder ( view );
                return viewHolder;
            }
        };
        userslist.setAdapter ( adapter );
        adapter.startListening ();
    }

    public static class FindFriendViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView userName;
        ImageView profileImage;

        public FindFriendViewHolder (@NonNull View itemView) {
            super ( itemView );
            userName = itemView.findViewById ( R.id.username1 );
            profileImage = itemView.findViewById ( R.id.profilepicture );

        }


    }
}
```

The rules of my database:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
      ".write":"true",
    "users":{
    "$user_id":{
       ".read": "auth.uid === $user_id",
       ".write": "auth.uid === $user_id"

    }
  }
}
}
```

I expect to show all the users from my databse.But the activity is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting :

```
ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("FirstName");
```

And then use that to initialize the FirebaseUI adapter:

```
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Users> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Users> ()
        .setQuery(ref, Users.class )
```

While I don't know your data model, it seems unlikely that you'd have a list of users under `/FirstName`, which is what is required to show those users with the FirebaseUI adapter.

More likely ref should be initialized as:

```
ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
1-   ref=firebaseDatabase.getReference("FirstName");
2-   ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
  //**HERE WHERE YOU SHOULD FETCH THE DATA FROM YOUR DATABASE**



           String value=dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

            list.add(value);

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                 list.clear();
                String value=dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

                list.add(value);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

and finally your database should be like this : 
[image: pic]
hope that works for you

Comment: My database looks like this: primary key for users-below are the first name and the second name for user details.

Comment: could you add some pictures?

Comment: I put in a link the picture of my database.

Comment: ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(the_id) 
then  ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
  //**HERE WHERE YOU SHOULD FETCH THE DATA FROM YOUR DATABASE**



           String value=dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

            list.add(value);

            }