# Can't get the others users name

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to make an activity for a chat app with only a textview that it shows me the first name of every user,but i'm getting the first name of the user who is logged in,not for others.Here is my database:

[image]

The message activity:

```
public class MessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView username;
    FirebaseUser fuser;
    DatabaseReference reference;
    Intent intent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView ( R.layout.activity_message );
       TabLayout appBarLayout=findViewById ( R.id.tab_2);



            username=findViewById ( R.id.username1 );

            intent=getIntent ();
            String userid=intent.getStringExtra ( "userid" );
            fuser= FirebaseAuth.getInstance ().getCurrentUser ();
            reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance ().getReference ("users").child ( "FIRST NAME");
            reference.addValueEventListener ( new ValueEventListener () {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange (@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    User user=dataSnapshot.getValue (User.class);
                    username.setText ( user.getFirstName () );

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled (@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            } );
        }


    }
```

The xml for message activity

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MessageActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name" />

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF">

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            >

        </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I expect to appear in the TextView the First Name of the user i want to talk.

Comment: @Cosmin in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56657172/9819031) question, the database image contains the key which you are trying to hide in this question, please be careful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the database you have the filed "FIRSTNAME" and in your code you have

```
.child ( "FIRST NAME");
```

Both values must be the same. Change the .child to this

```
.child ( "FirstName");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have almost done but just forgot to add other user id and get other user info:-

```
reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance ().getReference ("users").child("other user id").child ( "FIRST NAME");
            reference.addValueEventListener ( new ValueEventListener () {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange (@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    User user=dataSnapshot.getValue (User.class);
                    username.setText ( user.getFirstName () );

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled (@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            } );
```